# geth account import or new command doesn't create an account; instead returns Killed

Tags: kubernetes, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth, quorum

I'm trying to create/import a new ethereum account using geth, but instead of returning public address, geth returns `Killed`. I'm using [quorumengineering/quorum](https://hub.docker.com/r/quorumengineering/quorum) Docker image on a Kubernetes cluster.

Here's account creation script:

```
echo -n passwordstring > passwordfile
echo -n 82f74b773d7f948153d7eb8c192bd9819e3e94073d8bdc0e03d659aa42cd34ba > privateKey
geth --datadir . account import --password passwordfile privateKey
```

Instead of returning created new account's public address, the script returns:

```
INFO [07-09|16:43:48.932] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
Killed
```

Similar error is returned when I try importing or creating account interactively with `geth account new` followed by `kubectl exec -it <pod-name> sh`.

Things work fine when I use Quorum docker container (`docker run -it --entrypoint="sh" quorumengineering/quorum`) in my machine.

**EDIT: [ethereum/client-go](https://hub.docker.com/r/ethereum/client-go) image gives a more descriptive error message**

```
INFO [07-09|19:03:09.094] Bumping default cache on mainnet         provided=1024 updated=4096
WARN [07-09|19:03:09.095] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=4096 updated=1316
INFO [07-09|19:03:09.097] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [07-09|19:03:09.098] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
ERROR[07-09|19:03:09.098] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-09|19:03:09.099] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-09|19:03:09.099] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-09|19:03:09.099] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-09|19:03:09.099] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-09|19:03:09.099] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-09|19:03:10.100] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=3 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-09|19:03:10.100] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=3 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[07-09|19:03:10.101] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=3 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
Killed
```

I tried with `--nousb` flag but no help. I'm trying to enable `pcscd.socket` following instructions from https://superuser.com/questions/773257/scardestablishcontext-service-not-available